# Where to put OAuth logic?

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth, service-layer, actioncontroller

I'm using Zend Framework in a project, and I'm creating a controller only for authentication.
In this project we'll accept that a user signs up through a account of other sites like facebook, twitter, myspace, etc.. For this we will be using OAuth. But I'm having a doubt where I should put the logic for each OAuth site related authentication? Only the facebook, for example, occupied 50 lines of code in my controller, and in this way my controllers will not be thin...

I wonder where I should put this.
Create an Zend_Auth adapter for each one of the sites, create a service only to this, what is the best way?

And sorry the poor english. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JF Austin](https://github.com/jfaustin) has a fairly [generic OAuth authentication adapter implementation](https://github.com/jfaustin/Zend_Auth_Adapter_Oauth/blob/master/zf1/library/Ja/Auth/Adapter/Oauth.php) that uses a [Zend_Oauth_Consumer](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.10/_Oauth_Consumer.html#Zend_Oauth_Consumer). Creating specific subclasses of this for Twitter, Facebook, etc seems to be straightforward from there. He even seems to have a [Twitter adapter](https://github.com/jfaustin/Zend_Auth_Adapter_Oauth/blob/master/zf1/library/Ja/Auth/Adapter/Oauth/Twitter.php) already. Use of the adapter is described in [his blog post](http://www.jasonawesome.com/2010/11/24/authenticating-to-twitter-with-zend_auth/) about it.

Alternatively, note [this one](https://github.com/lloydwatkin/Demos/blob/master/zendframework/auth/Oauth.php) by [Lloyd Watkin](https://github.com/lloydwatkin).

Upshot: all the OAuth logic is buried inside these adapters. Your controllers can then instantiate this authentication adapter, feed it to `Zend_Auth::authenticate($adapter)`, and then take action based upon the returned result, keeping the controller focused on the higher-level app wiring.

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot for the reply.

The OAuth part is now complete. Now I am in doubt about where I should handle these subclasses, I'm thinking of creating a method for each site within my class that handles user actions (Service Layer), something like _loginFacebook, _loginTwitter, what do you think? Again, thank you.

Comment: An `AuthService` with methods `authFacebook()`, `authTwitter()` etc sounds ok. Better might be an `AuthServiceInterface` with a single method `authenticate()`. Then create specific instances implementing this interface, for example: `AuthServiceTwitter implements AuthServiceInterface`, `AuthServiceFacebook implements AuthServiceInterface`, etc. Just thinking out loud.

Answer (score 1):

Your OAuth logic should live inside models as should all your buisiness logic.  Your controller should be left to do is control the program flow and setup view variables for use in your view script.

Kind regards
Garry